# Unable to launch Internet Explorer from Edge Browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

My client wants me to have a button in a webpage and when visiting this page in MS Edge Browser, clicking on that button will launch Internet Explorer with a URL. I have write the following code but it's does not working. Can anyone please give me suggestion.

```
function LaunchIE() {
        var obj = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        var ie = "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe";
        obj.Run('"' + ie + '"', 1);
    }
```

Comment: http://www.groovypost.com/howto/find-use-internet-explorer-windows-10-microsoft-edge/

Comment: also, activeX (thankfully) is not supported in Microsoft Edge - sso, you're SOOL there

Comment: thanks for the help. yes it is possible to launch IE from Edge. But is there any other way with JavaScript to launch IE from Edge while clicking a button.